It should be more obvious how to add titles to images
There's a related feature request from 2010, but I'm not sure that feature request is necessarily asking for the right thing.
Image tags have two attributes - alt text and titles. The alt text is used when the image can't be loaded and by screenreaders, but it's generally not visible to people unless they inspect the markup for the page. The title attribute is displayed to people when they hover over an image.
The feature request from 2010 is asking for the same text to be used as the alt text and the title. I'm not sure that this is correct.
From my understanding, the title of the image is a better place to give attribution and licensing information, such as when including an image created by someone else.
It is possible to include this, but the guidance on the editing help page, the template when inserting an image, and more don't really tell people how to do this.
Rather than using the same text for both alt and title, as previously proposed, a better solution would be to provide clear instructions/guidance for how to add both titles and alt text. Additional guidance for how to best use these two fields would also be appropriate for the editing help page.
Note that I'm making this as a new post due to the age of the other post and the fundamental different request.

Based on Shadow Wizard's answer and Mithical's comment, there are at least two editors in use. One of them has guidance and the other doesn't. Depending on which editor your view has, you may or may not see the in-line guidance.
Based on muru's comment, the information is buried in the Markdown help pages. You need to expand the section on images to see one example. There are more examples in the Advanced Links section, but that is not directly hyperlinked. Overall, the editing help page has rather poor accessibility.
So the issue may not be the lack of information, but the lack of discoverability and navigation of the content.
It seems like the solution may be two-fold:

Finish the rollout of the "new" editor everywhere. This was asked about in July 2024 without an answer (as of 1 August 2024). Having a single editor in all places and then making sure the good guidance is provided in-line is key.
Consider revisiting the structure of the Editing Help page. The current formatting makes it hard to read and navigate. It's very easy to miss content that's relevant, even when you're looking for it.


TL;DR: it was quite obvious in the old editor, however I do agree SE made it much worse in the new editors that replace it. I'll elaborate on each of those below.

Old Editor: available when e.g. writing an answer or editing
In this editor, I think it's already clear enough how to add a title to images, for those who look for it.
Suppose John wants to add a title to an image. John see the question mark icon on the editor, and click it:

And that is it, it's right there (after clicking "Images"), black on orange:

This should be clear enough, and two buttons away. Having it shown e.g. in the image upload dialog means it would have to contain all the help text and it will just clutter the dialog.
Middleway editor: Ask Question editor
John is going to have hard time now to figure how to add a title. Still possible though. First thing to do is clicking the "Images" link which should open the tips for images:

Alas! That isn't really helpful though:

Nothing about title or tooltip here. But our John spot the "More" link, and bravely clicks it, to reach the Markdown help page. Sifting through the menu, John reach the holy grail, the section about Images:

So, title for image works the same way as title for a link. But wait, how to add title to a link? And why would I be smiling? OK, let's keep  going, time to go to the section about Links:

This isn't clear even here, but our John is smart and finally can figure how to do that. Even with broken HTML in the example.
New Editor: available as opt-in, replacing the answer/edit editor
John is now faced with a nice looking and modern editor, but still wonders how to add title to the image. Luckily, there's help icon:

Which leads right to the Markdown help page which we discussed above already.
Poor John needs a coffee now.

What site is this from? I don't see this on Meta SE or Software Engineering SE. This is what I see, which doesn't contain any references to "tooltip" or an advanced help section. The page that "More" takes you to also doesn't indicate how to apply a tooltip.

@ThomasOwens I see the same thing here on Meta SE (using Firefox Beta on Android): https://i.sstatic.net/QSjbYv6n.png (and just Ask Ubuntu, same thing there)

I don't understand how you get this view. But somewhere, there is a view that doesn't explain how to add tooltip/title text to an image. It's also not explained on the editing help page in the Help Center. So there is still a change to be made somewhere to make this guidance available everywhere and to update the Help Center.

@ThomasOwens - It does appear to be present in the Help Center. MSE uses the "new" editor; on other sites, clicking the help icon in the corner and then the "images" tab results in the guidance shown in Shadow's answer.

@ThomasOwens in the editing help, it says "Images are exactly like links ...", and on the Links sections, tool tips are covered in the advanced section hidden behind "show more"

@Mithical It's not just MSE - it's the same on Software Engineering. So this "new" editor is the one missing the guidance.

@muru That is not obvious. Perhaps poorly written, because I had to read it multiple times to understand what you were referring to. A lack of a link from the images section to the links section also made it hard to navigate. Very poor usability, at least, to understand how to write accessible content.

I agree that the information already exists, but I believe it's incomplete. Currently it just says "tooltip" without explaining what it is

@ThomasOwens Even on MSE, the new editor is opt-in; I just tested it, and it does not show anything resembling your screen shot: the “?” icon just opens the editing help page in a new tab. Otherwise, on all sites I tested, the editor looks as in Shadow’s screenshot. Are you sure you are not using some private CSS/scripts/whatever?

@ThomasOwens to whom do you want to make it obvious? If you're looking for something to show a new user, just link directly to the Advanced subsection of the Links (like I did) or Images section  - the help page is great in that the targeted section is put at the top. If for a random user browsing through the help, then it's tough: everybody has favoured features of markdown syntax that they'd like to be presented upfront, but I'm OK with having the basics covered in visible sections and details hidden in collapaed-by-default subsections.

@EmilJeřábek I don't have any custom CSS or scripts, no. I'm not a fan of user scripts and custom CSS because of things like this - having a shared user experience helps people actually help each other.

@muru Obvious to someone look for help. I spent over 15 minutes trying to figure out why my text was being treated as alt text and not a tooltip and then how to add a tooltip to an image. The guidance in the editor that I had didn't address it (see my screenshot to see what I saw) and I missed it in the Help Center page. If a person is looking for specific information and can't readily find it, that's a problem. Especially when it comes to making content accessible. Having good alt text and titles improve the accessibility of the content for everyone.

Oh, now I finally figured it out! The difference is that Thomas Owen’s screenshot is from the Ask Question editor, whereas the editor as in Shadow’s screenshot is used in all other instances (edit a question, or post/edit an answer). It’s the “old” editor in both cases.

@ThomasOwens ah, I forgot the mess SE made with the editors, and how each section use a different editor. I used the editor in the answer I was writing, but I agree the editor in the Ask Question page is indeed far worse, help-wise. I'll edit my answer soon.

@ThomasOwens done.

I'm pretty sure part of the problem is the layout of the editing page, too. When you put big red circles around it, it's easy to find. But I honestly don't think I saw that one-liner lost in the middle of other text that had one word to refer to titles. I think that the example from the old editor applied to the new editor and some reformatting of the markdown help page would go a long way.

@ThomasOwens agreed, perhaps this can fit as a self answer, focusing on what you want to be changed.

@ShadowWizard Yeah. I need to spend a little bit looking really hard at the help page to have some concrete thoughts. Rolling out the editor has already been asked about, though.

Just as an alternative, since the question says "the title of the image is a better place to give attribution and licensing information, such as when including an image created by someone else", a creative use of markdown tables I have seen on some sites is providing captions (including for attribution). These would look like:








Screenshot by user muru



Markdown source:
| [![Screenshot of Meta SE answer editor showing help for images][2]][1] |
|:-:|
| Screenshot by user [muru][3] |


Screenshots of how it renders:









Screenshot in normal mode
Screenshot with dark mode force-enabled



It does look kinda-sorta good, with the borders and table shading helping to delineate mostly-white images which blend into the page background (for which quote formatting was misused in the past), and allowing the image to be centered (for which people often add white padding in the image itself, ruining dark mode while still not getting proper centering).
I'm not saying it's a good use of tables, just that it is one I have seen (though I don't have an example on hand - it's difficult to search for this without using the Data Explorer). If anything it drags us back to dark days of the early web when everything was tables. Tables on top of tables. Tables inside tables. Tables everywhere. Only tables...

Frame challenge: Don't use title text
The title attribute is not accessible to some users, depending on what screen reader they are using (see this SO answer). Even users who could access title text might not think to wag their mouse over (or long tap on, etc.) images. To ensure everyone gets the same information (and not the same information twice for those using other screen readers), you really shouldn't use title text.
I also wouldn't use tables for this, since that's also a clunky experience for screen readers.
How about... plain text, right under the image? That also makes it easy to copy for anyone who actually needs to use the attribution.

Plain text under the image loses context, especially in machine readability. It becomes difficult to associate the info with the image itself. Alt text is absolutely wrong, since that's what screenreaders are supposed to use (in addition to being what gets displayed if the image source is blocked or otherwise unavailable). Looking at what attributes are available on images, maybe data-* is an option, but that's for custom app-specific data. Some hint at licensing should be embedded as an attribute in the HTML.

@ThomasOwens If they're going to add features to the editor, sure, more options would be available (or why stop there? have the surrounding link by default point to an editable metadata page like Wikipedia does). But machine readability shouldn't come at the expense of actual people, most of whom won't be able to set up or use anything as complicated as HTML attributes.

I don't follow the "at the expense of actual people". Screen readers and assistive technology should read alt text, so they should be a textual description of the image. It shouldn't contain titles or metadata about the image, because it harms the readability. The other option is the title, and including a brief license callout in the title is widely accepted. If screen readers aren't behaving properly, that's the problem of the screen reader and not the content author. Until something better is given, title is it. That doesn't mean it shouldn't also be in the text around the image, though.

@ThomasOwens Most screen readers read out the title text, so that's duplicating any license information you've included in the visible parts of the post. (You're correct that you wouldn't use alt text for licensing.) I have never heard of the title text being used for this. If you want to provide attribution to machines, the way I have heard to do this (eg by the CC wiki) is RDFa, which was specifically designed for machine consumption (unlike title text). Unfortunately, it is not supported in SE markdown.
